# Week view style for full month view in angular calendar (mattlewis92)

Tags: angular, angular-calendar

I am using the [angular-calendar from mattlewis92](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink).

*I would like to add the week view style to the month view*

**Current** - Week view style:

[image]

**Desired** - Month with the week view style (made with paint)

[image]

I have been struggling with this but couldn't find any solution. 
I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? This is what I have concluded but it looks like the week view component itself is not possible with this. The way it scatters the display of events is not grouped per day but by event row per day.